# What is the proper syntax for valuing Asian options with DX-Analytics

Tags: python, finance

I recently installed the DX-Analytics package for python. I'm trying to value an Asian option for which the averaging period is a subset of the time to maturity (i.e. the averaging date starts 3 months from now and lasts for 3 months at which point the option expires). I understand that you have to use mean_value in the payoff function somehow, although the syntax isn't clear. I also assume that you need to define the averaging period somewhere, again I'm assuming that this would be done by adding constants to the market environment, but not sure.

What is the proper syntax to value this type of option using DX-Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

I had an email exchange with the creator of DX-Analytics and it seems this particular style of Asian option may not be possible out of the box.